# Initializing Perl variables using eval

Tags: perl, variables, scope, eval

I'm guessing this should be something obvious to those knowing Perl, but I simply don't get it... I also guess it has to do with problems described in [Perl scoping « darkness](http://darkness.codefu.org/wordpress/2003/03/perl-scoping/) - but I cannot apply any of that in my case.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# call with:
# ./test.pl

use strict;

my $tvars = "my \$varA = 1;
my \$varB = 2;
my \$varC = 3;
";

my @lines = split /\n/, $tvars;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  print "$line\n";
  eval $line; warn $@ if $@;
}

#~ print "$varA\n"; # Global symbol "$varA" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 18.
#~ print "$varB\n"; # Global symbol "$varB" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 19.
#~ print "$varC\n"; # Global symbol "$varC" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 20.

$tvars = "our \$varA = 1;
our \$varB = 2;
our \$varC = 3;
";

@lines = split /\n/, $tvars;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  print "$line\n";
  eval $line; warn $@ if $@;
}

print "$varA\n"; # Global symbol "$varA" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 33.
print "$varB\n"; # Global symbol "$varB" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 34.
print "$varC\n"; # Global symbol "$varC" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 35.
```

Simply speaking, I'd like to have something like "`$varA = 1;`" written as a string (text file); and I'd like `perl` to `eval` it, so that afterwards I have access to variable "`$varA`" in the same script - the errors I get when I try to access those after an `eval` are in the comments of the code above (however, no warnings are reported during the `eval`). (*I'm guessing, what I'd need is something like "global" variables, if the `eval` runs in a different context than the main script?*)

How would I go about doing that? Do I have to go through all of that package definition business, even for a simple script like the above?

Comment: in general, `eval "$line; 1" or warn $@` is a safer way to call string eval.  There is an annoying edge case with eval called in a DESTROY method which will break the `warn $@ if $@` pattern since it clears `$@` even though the eval failed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It has everything to do with scoping. The variables are declared with `my` inside the eval expression. This makes them local to the `eval` statement and not accessible once the `eval` statement exits. You can declare them first, though:

```
my ($varA, $varB, $varC);  # declare outside the eval statement

my $tvars = "\$varA = 1;
\$varB = 2;
\$varC = 3;
";

eval $tvars;
# local $varA, $varB, $varC variables are now initialized
```

or as you suggest, you can use global variables. The easiest (though not necessarily the "best" way) is to prepend `::` to all variable names and get them in the main package.

```
my $tvars = "\$::varA = 1;
\$::varB = 2;
\$::varC = 3;
";

eval $tvars;
print "A=$::varA, B=$::varB, C=$::varC\n";
```

Now when you tried `our` variables in your example, you actually were initializing package (global) variables. But outside the `eval` statement, you still need to qualify (i.e., specify the package name) them in order to access them:

```
$tvar = "our \$foo = 5";
eval $tvar;

print $main::foo;    # ==> 5
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @mob - those examples help a lot! I'm liking the double colon `::` way, not too many changes from the way the problem was originally written... Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you do `eval $string`, `$string` is evaluated as its own subroutine which has its own lexical scope.  From [`perldoc -f eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
In the first form [in which the argument is a string], the return value of EXPR is parsed and 
executed as if it were a little Perl program. The value of the expression (which is itself 
determined within scalar context) is first parsed, and if there were no errors, executed in the 
lexical context of the current Perl program, so that any variable settings or subroutine and format 
definitions remain afterwards.
```

So, in other words, if you have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
eval "my $foo=5;";
print "$foo\n";
```

you'll get an error:

```
Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name at -e line 3.
Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name at -e line 4.
```

However, if you initialize your variables first, you're fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $foo;
eval "\$foo=5;";
print "$foo\n"; #prints out 5, as expected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Jack Maney - good to have that noted; however, the double colon specifier `::` does the trick for me in this case to avoid these errors.. Cheers!