# Setting variables in perl config file eval

Tags: perl, variables, hash, eval, config

I've got a perl script and a .config file and want to store some hashes in the config file with some variables as its value, then dynamically change them from my perl script.

Config File:

```
$hash{"hello"} = ["$blah", "$blah2"];
```

And my perl script:

```
if (-e ".config")
{
    $blah = "hello";
    $blah2 = "world!";

    eval ('require(".config")');

    $val1 = $hash{"hello"}[0];
    $val2 = $hash{"hello"}[1];
    print "$val1 $val2\n";

    # Now I want to CHANGE blah and blah2
    $blah = "world!";
    $blah2 = "hello";

    $val1 = $hash{"hello"}[0];
    $val2 = $hash{"hello"}[1];
    print "$val1 $val2\n";
}
```

But both prints show `hello world!` as if the change didn't happen.. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Any examples of this? New to perl.. Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506782/initializing-perl-variables-using-eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Strange... I've never seen a question of this sort previously, and then variations on it (which are different enough to clearly not be just a cross-post) appeared both here and on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1035710) in the same day.)

The point you're missing is that

```
$hash{"hello"} = ["$blah", "$blah2"];
```

just copies the *values* of `$blah` and `$blah2` into (an anonymous array referenced by) `$hash{hello}`.  It does not create any lasting connection between the hash and `$blah`/`$blah2`.

As a side note, none of the quotes in that line serve any purpose.  It would more commonly be written as:

```
$hash{hello} = [$blah, $blah2];
```

Or, if you want to create references so that `$blah` and `$hash{hello}[0]` are forever linked and changing one will also change the other:

```
$hash{hello} = [\$blah, \$blah2];
```

Note that in this case, you **must not** use quotes. Although `"$blah"` and `$blah` are equivalent, `"\$blah"` and `\$blah` are not - `\$blah` gives you a reference to `$blah`, but `"\$blah"` gives you the literal string "$blah" with no variables involved at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately my implementation requires the quotes around the values, it's actually meant to be a command (but I've just omitted them here for simplicity). For example: `$hash{"hello"} = ["somecommand $blah", "somecommand2 $blah2"]`. I've been testing some variations of it including `\($blah)` `(\$blah)` and so on, but none seem to work. They all either pring out `hello world` twice instead of `hello world` `world hello` or error..

Comment: In that case you're going to have to assign `$blah = (the result of "somecommand $blah")` and put a reference to that into your hash. There's no way to take a mutable reference to a literal string.

Comment: In that case, how would I go about replacing String Literals? I really need to be able to replace the string literals in the .config file and return the command without actually changing the data in the .config as it is a template.

Comment: The normal way to do that would be by assigning to `$hash{hello}` rather than by changing another variable and expecting the hash to update automatically.  `$blah = "world"; $hash{hello}[0] = $blah;` If you mean to replace the text of the command with its output, you could streamline this with something like `$hash{hello}[0] = run_command($hash{hello}[0]);` or even `$_ = run_command($_) for @{$hash{hello}};`, but it's not completely clear whether that's your ultimate intention.

Comment: Hmm, the issue is that I don't want to change the .config file. This is because `$hash{"hello"}`s commands could be called using different `blah` multiple times. So I thought of keeping the string literal `blah` in the value and then simply changing the value of `blah` when I needed to.

Comment: Assigning to `%hash` doesn't change the config file. Those commands would go in the main program, where you're currently setting `$blah = "world!";`.